Unable to install Powershell 7 on Windows Server 2016 DataCenter .. Error "Access denied"
I have purchased a VM where I connect to it using RDP. now I downloaded 2 files from the web; Microsoft Edge exe file + PowerShell 7.0 MSI file, as follow: -

then using the administrator user >> i installed Microsoft Edge without issue. but when i tired to install PowerShell MSI file, i got access denied:-

I contacted the company which offers the VM and they mentioned the follow:-

Please check this link how to install newer PowerShell:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-windows?view=powershell-7.4
we provide unmanaged services which means that we are responsible for
the provision of hardware, but maintaining and configuring servers on
operating system level and above remains the responsibility of the
customer.
By default we place zero restrictions on what kind of software you
wish to run on your server. While the standard protocols to access a
server are SSH (Secure Shell Protocol) and RDP (Remote Desktop
Protocol), for advanced users we also offer Contabo API to manage
resources using HTTP: https://api.contabo.com/

What could be causing the Access Denied error?

I am not sure what happened exactly, but based on @Ramhound seems after i run this command:-
C:\Users\Administrator>msiexec.exe /package PowerShell-7.4.3-win-x64.msi /quiet ADD_EXPLORER_CONTEXT_MENU_OPENPOWERSHELL=1 ADD_FILE_CONTEXT_MENU_RUNPOWERSHELL=1 ENABLE_PSREMOTING=1 REGISTER_MANIFEST=1 USE_MU=1 ENABLE_MU=1 ADD_PATH=1

I start seeing PowerShell 7 when i right click on a folder:-
enter image description here


What could be causing the Access Denied error?

I wouldn't be able to say the exact reason you are getting the Access Denied error.  You can bypass the error by installing PowerShell with the following in an elevated command prompt:
msiexec.exe /package PowerShell-7.4.3-win-x64.msi /quiet ADD_EXPLORER_CONTEXT_MENU_OPENPOWERSHELL=1 ADD_FILE_CONTEXT_MENU_RUNPOWERSHELL=1 ENABLE_PSREMOTING=1 REGISTER_MANIFEST=1 USE_MU=1 ENABLE_MU=1 ADD_PATH=1

